# SQL query with concat some fields . (MySql)

Tags: mysql, sql, string

I using MySQL.
I will explain my question by example.. I have those 2 records:

```
Id       Name        Role
3004     Jason       x
3004     Jason       y
```

I want to make a query that make Group by the Id , and concat all the Roles of this Id to one field with ',' between them.

```
Id    Name     Roles
3004  Jason    x,y
```

Is it possible?

Comment: The answer is `group_concat()` and there are many examples of how to use it.

Comment: `select
id,
Name,
group_concat(Role) as Roles
from table_name 
group by id`

Answer (score 0):

Use this query:

```
SELECT Id, Name, GROUP_CONCAT(Roles) as Roles_grouped
FROM your_table
GROUP BY Id, Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

also you can use scalar function to do this.

```
SELECT ID,Name,GetRolesByID(ID) FROM your_Table GROUP BY ID,Name
```

'GetRolesByID' is the scalar function that concat the roles of the ID given in parameters.